# RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext() is null while writing Unit test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

Java 17, SpringBoot application. I tried to implement a Retry logic. Functionally, the code is working perfectly, but when I'm trying to write a JUnit test for the same, it fails as `RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()` is null.

Method:

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${retry.maxRetry}", 
backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${retry.maxInterval}",
            multiplierExpression = "${retry.delayMultiplier}", maxDelayExpression = "${retry.maxDelay}"))
    public Session connect() {
        retryCountConnect = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
        Session sshSession = null;
        try {
            sshSession = sshSessionPool.getSession();
            sshSession.connect();
            return sshSession;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred during SshSftp connect, retry count:{}, error details:{}",
                    retryCountConnect, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Test case:

```
class ConnectionTest {
    @Mock
    Session sshSession;
    @Mock
    SshSessionPool sshSessionPool;
    @Mock
    MockedStatic<BasicSshSessionPool> basicSshSessionPoolMockedStatic;
    @Mock
    MockedStatic<AopContext> aopContext;
    Channel channel;
    SshSftpConnection sshSftpConnection;

    @BeforeEach
    @SneakyThrows
    void setUp() {
        channel = Mockito.mock(ChannelExec.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        basicSshSessionPoolMockedStatic.when(() -> BasicSshSessionPool.create(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sshSessionPool);
        sshSftpConnection = spy(new SshSftpConnection("host", "username", "password", 22));
        when(sshSessionPool.getSession()).thenReturn(sshSession);
        when(sshSession.openChannel(anyString())).thenReturn(channel);
        aopContext.when(AopContext::currentProxy).thenReturn(sshSftpConnection);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() {
        aopContext.close();
        basicSshSessionPoolMockedStatic.close();
    }

    @Test
    void connect() throws Exception {
        doReturn(sshSession).when(sshSessionPool).getSession();
        Session actual = sshSftpConnection.connect();
        verify(sshSession, times(1)).connect();
        assertEquals(sshSession, actual);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.retry.RetryContext.getRetryCount()" because the return value of "org.springframework.retry.support.RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.retry.RetryContext.getRetryCount()" because the return value of "org.springframework.retry.support.RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()" is null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: You need to show the entire test case - there must be a Spring test context (e.g. `@SpringBootTest`) for this to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this functionality is to mock the RetryContext class and then register the mocked instance of RetryContext class to RetrySynchronizationManager.

You can register as below in your set up method

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    RetryContext retryContext = Mockito.mock(RetryContext.class);
    RetrySynchronizationManager.register(retryContext);
}
```

Doing such you will be able to get the retry count without any Null Pointer Exception.