# Spock test fails, RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext() is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-retry

I wrote a Spock test to exercise a service using Spring-retry, the test context doesn't get setup correctly somehow.

The specific error is (line breaks inserted by @kriegaex):

```
[ERROR]
  IntegrationTestSpec.test success the first time:25 » 
  NullPointer Cannot invoke "org.springframework.retry.RetryContext.getRetryCount()"
  because the return value of
  "org.springframework.retry.support.RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()"
  is null
```

There is a [previous question asking about the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73380168/217324) but there is no code reproducing the problem provided so it didn't get very far. This question has full code included below, it's also at https://github.com/nathan-hughes/spring-retry-examples.

The failing test:

```
package ndhtest

import spock.lang.Specification
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import spock.lang.Subject

@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyRetryableService, RandomNumberService])
class IntegrationTestSpec extends Specification {

    @SpringBean
    RandomNumberService randomNumberService = Stub(RandomNumberService)

    @Subject
    @Autowired
    MyRetryableService myRetryableService

    def "test success the first time"() {
        given:
        randomNumberService.randomNumber() >> 1

        when:
        int result = myRetryableService.doStuff('hello')

        then:
        result == 1
    }
}
```

The code to test:

```
package ndhtest;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final MyRetryableService myRetryableService;

    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("starting application");
        SpringApplication.run( SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);
        log.info("finishing application");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String ... args) {
        log.info("executing command line runner");
        try {
            int i = myRetryableService.doStuff("hello");
            log.info("myRetryableService returned {}", i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("caught exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The service that does the retrying, it has logging that gets the retry count, this works when running the code outside of the Spock test:

```
package ndhtest;

import java.util.Random;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetrySynchronizationManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyRetryableService {

    private final RandomNumberService randomNumberService;

    @Retryable(value = {RetryableException.class}, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay=100))
    public int doStuff(String s) {

        log.info("doing stuff with {}, try = {}", s, RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() + 1);
        int i = randomNumberService.randomNumber();

        // simulate having something bad happen that is recoverable
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            String issue = "oops";
            log.warn("condition = {}", issue);
                throw new RetryableException(issue);
            }

        // simulate having something bad happen that is not recoverable
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            String issue = "ohnoes";
            log.warn("condition = {}", issue);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(issue);
        }

        return i;
    }

    @Recover
    public int recover(RetryableException e, String s) {

        log.info("in recover for RetryableException, s is {}", s);
        return -1;
    }

    @Recover
    public int recover(RuntimeException e, String s) {

        log.info("in recover for RuntimeException, s is {}", s);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Supporting cast:

```
package ndhtest;

import java.util.Random; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RandomNumberService {

    private Random random = new Random();

    public int randomNumber() {
        return random.nextInt();
    }
}
```

```java
package ndhtest;

public class RetryableException extends RuntimeException {

    public RetryableException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }

    public RetryableException(String message) {
        this(message, null);
    }
}
```

the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>ndhtest</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-retry-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <groovy.version>4.0.5</groovy.version>
    <springboot.version>3.1.6</springboot.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>
    <spock.version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</spock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>ndhtest.SpringBootConsoleApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <useModulePath>false</useModulePath> <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809 -->
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec</include>
                </includes>
                    <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                </statelessTestsetReporter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Interestingly, when running the whole test suite, i.e. `HappyPathSpec` first, it works both with `mvn test` and in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). If I run the test in isolation, however, I can reproduce the problem, again either from IDE or by `mvn test -Dtest=IntegrationTestSpec`. Is the situation identical for you?

Comment: For me, it also works if I remove the `classes` argument from `@SpringBootTest`. Not being a Spring user, I am not sure if the problem is the way you wrote the test, something in Spring Test or Spock. I am going to alert Leonard. I am sure, he can shed more light on this.

Comment: BTW, you can update Surefire from the old milestone to 3.2.5, get rid of `<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>` (should be long fixed) and maybe bump Groovy to 4.0.6 in sync with what the Spock version you use also suggests. But all of these do not have any influence on the problem as such.

Comment: fyi the linked code is updated, I commented out the problematic annotation but it is still visible, and putting it back should trigger the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to get this working:

1. Use `@SpringBootTest` without `classes` argument.
2. Add `RetrySynchronizationManager.register(Mock(RetryContext))` at the beginning of your test, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76052447/1082681) in the other question you also linked to. Then, you can continue to use `classes` in `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Thank you, removing the classes argument was what I needed. I figured it was something silly. I guess I was keeping spring from constructing the test context by limiting the classes?

Comment: Maybe. People like Leonard and Björn probably know better.

Comment: I think using 1. is fine, when using `classes` you better know all the things you need for your tests, otherwise you'll end up with unsatisfied dependencies as OP has noticed. I haven't used `spring-retry` myself so I can't say anything to 2., but it might or might not work for this, only trying it will tell.